# How do I extract certain bits from a number and put them in a new variable?

Tags: c, byte, bitwise-operators, bit

So today I had an exam where I needed to write some programs and one of the assignments was really hard for me:

```
unsigned char msg_to_opmag (unsigned short msg);

int main()
{
   short msg = 0x08CF //0x08CF = 1000 1100 1111
   msg_to_opmag(msg);
}
```

I need to write a function that extracts the bold bits (1**0001**1**001**111) so that would be 00001001 (char has 8 bits)

the output in this example would be:

> hex number: 0x08CF turns in 0x09 after being extracted.

My question is how do I write this function?

Comment: Read about bit-masking (and bit-shifting).

Comment: Could you at least write some code ? SO isn't a exam / homework solver.

Comment: Could you also emphasize on the pattern used to locate the "bold" bits ? Is it all the 0's followed by a 1 ? Or is is the 2nd to 5th bits + 7th to 9th ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks I'll take a look at that. We have not discussed bit masking in class so it's new for me!

Comment: @ValentinTrinqué I know. the exam is already over, I failed and now I am wondering what I could've done better. I mean the 2 tot 5 + 7th to 9th. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @arnofrederiks Yes I understood, but the things is especially because you failed, you should try your own. Giving you the solution won't help to progress. Just the opposite. Write some code and when totally stuck, seek for help.

Comment: @arnofrederiks "Read about bit-masking (and bit-shifting)." is a good advice. It will help you. Using this technique, you will be able to apply some operations on each bits of your `short` variable and extract the needed bits.

Comment: @ValentinTrinqué You are absolutely right!  I am going to work haha, If I'm stuck, or if I found a solution, I will post it here! thanks for the good advice! :)

Comment: @arnofrederiks Glad to hear it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about bit-masking and bit-shifting.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MASKA 0x038 // 0000 0011 1000
#define MASKB 0x780 // 0111 1000 0000
#define SHIFTA 3    //        XX X-->
#define SHIFTB 4    // 0XXX X--- >

int main()
{
   short msg = 0x08CF;
   short msg2 = ((msg & MASKA) >> SHIFTA) | ((msg & MASKB) >> SHIFTB);

   printf("0x%04x -> 0x%02x\n", msg, msg2);
}
```

Output:

```
0x08cf -> 0x09
```

Comment: I was really struggling with the 6th bit from the left. I am going to try some more bit shift/bit mask exercises! Thank you very much for this solution!